# Where is the community to ask accounting questions?

Tags: support, site-recommendation

I had asked [this question](https://money.stackexchange.com/q/52245/32575) on money.stackexchange.com but I got a comment that:

> This site is for personal finance questions. Accounting questions unrelated to personal finance are off-topic here.

Can anybody guide me to a community where I could ask general accounting-related questions?

Comment: Being married to one and hence knowin several, Accountants don't seem to use forums, they tend to ask the other accountants that they know. Many times I've suggested to the Significant Other to maybe try forum/ask-the-internets, only to receive incredulity in return..

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Looks like there's a proposal for [Accounting](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/102473/accounting) but it doesn't exist as an actual site yet.

> Proposed Q&A site for accounting professionals and people studying or working in the fields of financal accounting, management accounting or tax accounting.

You can certainly follow it but it looks like it's not doing too well... Perhaps if you share it with other accountants you can make it more successful!

Comment: And now it's dead...

Comment: Now there seems to exist an [accounting](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/accounting) tag in the Money & Personal Finance community.